# How to get current position(X Y) of div that i am dragging around in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my react project i would like to get current position of this div that i can drag around on screen. I mean current X Y coordinates

Comment: You can attach a dragover listener. You will get position in the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to listen to is the Drag Event - take a look at the [Mozilla Documentation for good examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event)

*Remember in React the events will be referred to in camel case - `onDragStart`, `onDragEnd`, etc.*

```js
// A sample drag handler where you are getting the elements coordinates
function onDragStartHandler (ev) {
    var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
}
```